# Writing a bmp-header in C++ style vs C style

Tags: c++

Long ago I wrote a function in C to write a bmp-header. I used binary operators to parse the uint_16's and uint_32's directly into a char[54] array, which took care of endianess and portability.

I've been learning C++ for a while now, and am now trying to rewrite that function in C++-Style using std::ofstream instead of FILE*. The c++ code I produced looks bad and doesn't deal with endianess. Is there a better, or more proper, way to do the C++-header? (preferably one that is portable and deals with endianess)

It currently looks like this:

```
void writeHeader(int width, int height, std::ofstream file)
{
    char bmpSign[2] = {'B', 'M'};
    uint filesize = width*height*3+54;
    uint reserved = 0;
    uint headersize = 54;
    uint infoHeader = 40;
    ushort colors = 1;
    ushort bitsPerPixel = 24;
    uint compression = 0;
    uint imgSize = width*height*3;
    uint xPels = 0;
    uint yPels = 0;
    uint usedColors = 0;
    uint impColors = 0;

    file.write(bmpSign, 2*sizeof(char));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(filesize),     sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(reserved),     sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(headersize),   sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(infoHeader),   sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(width),        sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(height),       sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(colors),       sizeof(ushort));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bitsPerPixel), sizeof(ushort));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(compression),  sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(imgSize),      sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(xPels),        sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(yPels),        sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(usedColors),   sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(impColors),    sizeof(int));
}
```

Thanks!

The C-Version of the header:

```
void parseInt16(uint16_t mem_head, uint8_t file_head[54], int offset)
{
  file_head[offset] = (mem_head & 0x00ff);
  file_head[offset + 1] = (mem_head & 0xff00) >> 8;
}

void parseInt32(uint32_t mem_head, uint8_t file_head[54], int offset) 
{   
  file_head[offset] = (mem_head & 0x000000ff);
  file_head[offset + 1] = (mem_head & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
  file_head[offset + 2] = (mem_head & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
  file_head[offset + 3] = (mem_head & 0xff000000) >> 24;
}

void writeHeader(int width, int height, FILE* bitmap_destination)
{

  uint8_t bmp_header[54];
  bmp_header[0] = 'B'; bmp_header[1] = 'M'; 

  //parsing the 32 or 16 bit numbers into byte form, little-endian.
  //function syntax: (value, Array of Bytes, Offset)

  parseInt32(width * height * 3 + 54, bmp_header, 2); //filesize
  parseInt32(0, bmp_header, 6);                   //reserved by software (0)
  parseInt32(54, bmp_header, 10 );                //headerOffset / Header size
  parseInt32(40, bmp_header, 14 );                    //infoHeaderSize
  parseInt32(width, bmp_header, 18);              //Width in pixels
  parseInt32(height, bmp_header, 22);             //Height in pixels
  parseInt16(1, bmp_header, 26);                  //Colors (1 per standard)
  parseInt16(24, bmp_header, 28);                 //bitsPerPixel (3 bytes/p)
  parseInt32(0, bmp_header, 30);                  //Compression (0 = none)
  parseInt32(width * height * 3, bmp_header, 34); //Image Size(bytes)
  parseInt32(0, bmp_header, 38);                  //xPelsPerMeter
  parseInt32(0, bmp_header, 42);                  //yPelsPerMeter
  parseInt32(0, bmp_header, 46);                  //Colors used (0 for all)
  parseInt32(0, bmp_header, 50);                  //important Colors (0 for all)

  fwrite(bmp_header, 1, 54, bitmap_destination); //writing the header to disk
}
```

Comment: How did you "deal with endianness" in the C version?

Comment: Why `sizeof(char)*2` instead of `sizeof(ushort)`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I added the C header! At least I *think* that deals with endianess...

Comment: @crush I have no idea. I will change that.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "portable" in this instance. Nothing here seems un-portable.

Comment: Please do not use short with sizeof(short), ... use <cstdint> (stdint.h) instead: int16_t with sizeof(int16_t), ...

Comment: @cmbasnett using a struct with pragmas, for example would be not portable.

Comment: @DieterLücking Good point.

Comment: For one, your C code always goes with the same endianness.  You are not checking whether the machine is big or little endian on the fly (a simple test).  Second, you are writing file in C++ while building the buffer and then writing it in one shot in C.  The latter is more efficient.  You should be able to do that in C++ as well.

Comment: Regarding _dealing with endianess_ you could also use the `htonl()` functions family from `arpa/inet.h` which is available in most POSIX compatible environments.

Comment: @BigBadWolf: Yeah looks like it does. But in the C++ version you've stripped that out for no apparent reason. Just put it back in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you have for dealing with endianness of a platform should be reused. That code is independent of whether you use `FILE*` or `std::fstream` to write the data out.

The only line you need to change is

```
fwrite(bmp_header, 1, 54, bitmap_destination);
```

That can be replaced by:

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bmp_header), 54);
```

Comment: Could create a `struct` for the header, and call `sizeof(BmpHeader)` too, no?

Comment: @crush, No. `sizeof(BmpHeader)` is not likely to be `54` due to padding between member variables of a `struct`.

Comment: @crush I can tell you for sure, that this will crash due to padding. You would have to declare such struct with `__declspec(align(1))` or similar, which is not portable.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek `pragma pack` seems to be quite a portable alternative.

Comment: @lisyarus how portable is quite portable? I thought it's just found in the gcc family.

Comment: @BigBadWolf nope, msvc, clang, and even borland and intel compilers seem to support this too.

Comment: @lisyarus oh wow. That's amazing. But it doesn't hurt to learn how to do it without, right?

Comment: @lisyarus It may be "quite portable", but it is still pragma - [it's compiler-specific by definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/): `This directive is used to specify diverse options to the compiler. These options are specific for the platform and the compiler you use. Consult the manual or the reference of your compiler for more information on the possible parameters that you can define with #pragma`.

Comment: @BigBadWolf surely, it doesn't. Learning is always a good thing to do :)

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek yes, it is. But if you are sure that you will be using only a predefined set of compilers, there is nothing bad in using these compilers' specific features. Futhermore, it seems that some pragmas, like `pragma once` or `pragma pack` are so widely spread that you can rely on them, if you are brave enough.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: Everything is compiler specific, really. Even features defined by the standard. I'd rely more heavily on such universal pragmas like `pack` and `once` than certain cutting edge or esoteric features of the standard.

Comment: Good read on [struct alignment padding](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/) forgot about this. Thanks for refresher.